# What is the recommended data type for scientific calculation in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, types

What is the most recommended data type to use in scientific calculation in .Net? Is it float, double or something else?

Comment: What are you calculating? I'd say it depends entirely on the data you're working with, what you're doing with it, and what your needs are.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Scientific values tend to be "natural" values (length, mass, time etc) where there's a natural degree of imprecision to start with - but where you may well want very, very large or very, very small numbers. For these values, `double` is generally a good idea. It's fast (with hardware support almost everywhere), scales up and down to huge/tiny values, and generally works fine if you're not concerned with exact `decimal` values.

`decimal` is a good type for "artificial" numbers where there's an exact value, almost always represented naturally as a decimal - the canonical example for this is currency. However, it's twice as expensive as `double` in terms of storage (8 bytes per value instead of 4), has a smaller range (due to a more limited exponent range) and is significantly slower due to a lack of hardware support.

I'd personally only use `float` if storage was an issue - it's amazing how quickly the inaccuracies can build up when you only have around 7 significant decimal places.

Ultimately, as the comment from "bears will eat you" suggests, it depends on what values you're talking about - and of course what you plan to do with them. Without any further information I suspect that `double` is a good starting point - but you should really make the decision based on the individual situation.

Comment: I like the "natural" vs. "artificial" distinction.

Answer (score 8):

Well, of course the term “scientific calculation” is a bit vague, but in general, it’s `double`.

`float` is largely for compatibility with libraries that expect 32-bit floating-point numbers. The performance of `float` and `double` operations (like addition) is exactly the same, so new code should always use `double` because it has greater precision.

However, the x86 JITter will never inline functions that take or return a `float`, so using `float` in methods could actually be slower. Once again, this is for compatibility: if it were inlined, the execution engine would skip a conversion step that reduces its precision, and thus the JITter could inadvertantly change the result of some calculations if it were to inline such functions.

Finally, there’s also `decimal`. Use this whenever it is important to have a certain number of decimal places. The stereotypical use-case is currency operations, but of course it supports more than 2 decimal places — it’s actually an 80-bit piece of data.

If even the accuracy of 64-bit `double` is not enough, consider using an external library for arbitrary-precision numbers, but of course you will only need that if your specific scientific use-case specifically calls for it.

Comment: Source on the inline claim? There was a bug that was fixed in 3.5 SP1 that didn't allow the JIT to inline functions that took value type parameters, but I can't think of any other issues.

Comment: Cannot find the source anymore, but I did mention the issue. The CLR evaluation stack only ever uses 64-bit values for floating-point numbers. Every time a 32-bit float is passed into a method, or a method returns a 32-bit float, the value from the evaluation stack is specifically converted to a 32-bit float in order to preserve its lack of precision.

Comment: Actually double is slower than float, as all new CPUs ship with SSE instructions (and have done for a long time). Without having the AVX instruction set, these allow you to do 4 float operations in one instruction or 2 double operations. This means that code such as Vector work (Vector addition, scaling, etc) there would theoretically be a 2x performance difference. [EDIT: float and double are the same speed, but for the same time you can do twice as much float work]

Answer (score 5):

`Double` seems to be the most reliable data type for such operations. Even WPF uses it extensively.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that decimals are much more expensive to use than floats/doubles (in addition to what Jon Skeet and Timwi wrote).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend double unless you need the value to be exact; decimal is for financial calculations that need this exactitude. Scientific calculations tolerate small errors because you can't exactly measure 1 meter anyways. Float only helps if storage is a problem (ie. huge matrices).